scroll transition SwiftUI multiple constraints
in SwiftUI, we have a new feature that indicates whether a view is the identity(is at the center of the scroll view) or not, my for each is in a HStack which is in a ScrollView:
struct MyUnwindsView: View {

   @State private var shouldScale = false
   var body: some View {

    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
         LazyHStack(spacing: 0) {
              ForEach(0..<10, id: \.self) { unwindViewData in
                            Rectangle()
                            .padding(4)
                            .id(UUID())
                            .scrollTransition { content, phase in
                                content
                                    .opacity(phase.isIdentity ? 1 : 0.6)
                                    .scaleEffect(phase.isIdentity ? 1 : 0.9)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .scrollTargetLayout()
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .accessibilityElement(children: .contain)
                .defaultScrollAnchor(.leading)
                .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
            }
    }

}

I also have a declared at the top of my struct:
@State private var shouldScale = false

Now in the code above, what I want to do is:
.scaleEffect(phase.isIdentity && shouldScale ? 1 : 0.9)

But I get the following error:
Main actor-isolated property 'shouldScale' can not be referenced from a non-isolated autoclosure

Is there anyway to get around this issue? In my example, the user can go to the edit context which I would set the shouldScale to false, and in that case, I want to make all the cards have the same size. But seems like I cannot access that property here.

That works perfectly, thank you so much! The UUID() is not right here, I just had to change to for privacy reasons from what the actual UUID in the code base was. @Sweeper

You should explicitly capture shouldScale in the closure's capture list:
.scrollTransition { [shouldScale] content, phase in
    content.scaleEffect(phase.isIdentity && shouldScale ? 1 : 0.9)
}

This way you are not capturing self, which is not Sendable. You are just capturing a Bool, which is Sendable.
